# Divs and vertical centering images inside divs

Tags: css, html

I'm new to working with divs, so I'm not too good at using them. I'm making a music blog, and I want the user to be able to see the picture for the post, and arrows on either side to go to next or previous posts. I'm having trouble centering the arrows in my parent div.

I searched a few things online, but nothing seemed to work. Here is my css for a simple test...

```
#picture_wrapper {
  width:550px;
  background-color:#00F;
  float:left;
}

#picture_container {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}

#left_arrow_container {
  float: left;
  top:50%;
  width: 20px;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #F00;
}

#right_arrow_container {
  float: right;
  top:50%;
  width: 20px;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

I set the arrow divs to have a background color of red, and I thought with this code the entire right and left sides would be red, but this is not the case. Only the area around my image is red. Here is the html that I am using.

```
<div id="picture_wrapper">
  <div id="left_arrow_container"><img src = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/slider_left_arrow.png' width = '20' height = '34px'/></div>
  <div id="picture_container"><center><img src = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DIIV+zachacry+cole+smith2.jpg' width = '500' /></center></div>
  <div id="right_arrow_container"><img src = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/slider_right_arrow.png' width = '20' /></div>
</div>
```

Here is how it is being displayed on my Dreamweaver now...
[pic1 http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/pic1.png](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/pic1.png)

Here is how I more or less want it to be displayed...
[pic2 http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/pic2.png](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/images/pic2.png)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `vertical-align: middle;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Lp5M9/2/

```css
#picture_wrapper { 
    background: #F00;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap; }
#left_arrow_container, #right_arrow_container {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#picture_container {
    background: #00F;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

​
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is really nice, but it doesn't work for all of my images. For example...

http://www.startingtofeelit.com/2012/06/24/lifetimes-summer-beats-per-minute/

That image is not very wide. I want the left arrow and right arrow to always be in the same position, and the image centered in between the two. Of course the arrows don't work yet (haven't made them into links yet), but you can cycle through the other posts by using the next/previous links at the top. I'm doing away with that once I get the arrows looking nicer.

Comment: Set a fixed width for `#picture_container`, and then add `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using absolute and relative position :), pretty much what I saw you were trying to achieve in your css, in order to top, left, right and bottom to work you must set a position (absolute, relative or fixed) and use your arrows as backgrounds

http://jsfiddle.net/wQqfp/2/

Comment: I'd second this one. Absolute positioning, 50% from top, and a negative top margin half of the height of the arrow.