# Trouble vertically centering a series of images contained in DIVs

Tags: html, css, optimization, center, vertical-alignment

I have a simple method for displaying a series of images that center horizontally by changing in CSS the `.container {width: 20%;}` depending on the number of images (i.e. 5 images = width: 20%;, 4 images = width: 25%, 3 images = width: 33.333% and so on.

However, I'm having trouble centering the complete set of images vertically. I've tried `margin: auto` for instance without success. Code below.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmmwQR

> **Question:**
>
> How can I center the series of images below vertically on the page?

**Images:**

*How it currently appears, positioned at the vertical top:*

[image]

*How it should appear, positioned in the vertical center:*

[image]

```css
div.box
 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
div.note {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-1" />
    <div class="note">Box 1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-2" />
    <div class="note">Box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-3" />
    <div class="note">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-4" />
    <div class="note">Box 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-5" />
    <div class="note">Box 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or some form of visual as to what you are expecting the outcome to be?

Comment: Good point, I should have added images in the beginning. Now included above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divs and vertical centering images inside divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696482/divs-and-vertical-centering-images-inside-divs) and a host of other answers found by searching SO.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob. I tried that, but the the linked example didn't seem to be working with the code above. The code in the linked example appears to be centering based on the image size, not a responsive page full height. I'll try again and see if I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

if your image's height will different from each other, you can use flex.

Here is the code pen link:

```
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bizedkhan/pen/vmmOBR)
```

if you need to center them from full page, see this.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bizedkhan/pen/YVVXXa)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the first doesn't seem to center the images vertically, and the second only centers the images vertically on some browsers. A universal non-flex method would be better.

Comment: Just to add, the first option centers vertically the elements, but I'm after an option that centers vertically all elements together on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the image a **Block** element:

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to center the images vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I managed to make put these boxes in the center:

```css
div.box
 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
div.note {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-1" />
    <div class="note">Box 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-2" />
    <div class="note">Box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-3" />
    <div class="note">Box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-4" />
    <div class="note">Box 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <img src="image-5" />
    <div class="note">Box 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working, this horizontally centers instead of vertical.

Comment: Sorry in that case I have no idea how to centre things vertically.

Comment: No trouble, thanks for taking the time to try helping!